# A specific space curve's length

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I'm trying to calculate a space curve's length.

$$r(t)=(3t^2-2t, t^3, 1-t)$$

$t$: from $0$ to $2$

So I have to derivate the $r(t)$, which makes:
$$r'(t)=(6t-2, 3t^2, -1)$$

And then I get the integral below, from the absolute value of $r'(t)$. And that is it, I'm stuck here. Somebody, please help!

$$\int_{0}^{2}\sqrt{9t^4+36t^2-24t+5}\,dt$$

Comment: I doubt that you can find an exact value; you may have to approximate the integral. (Maple can't do it.)

Comment: Are you sure you copied the correct parameterization?

Comment: @qmd Yes. Exactly as in the textbook.